Export azure KustoDB data to mongoDB
I have a kustoDB data around 10TB of size, the problem here is cluster is getting full hence bearing huge cost. Now I want to export entire kusto data to mongodb.
I tried creating a python script to move data in chunks but it has limitation that we can not fetch more that 64mb of data from kusto at one go.

Alternatively it is fine if we can move this data to cloud storage of azure.
